# Launching Steam Game requires acceptance of elevation dialogs from Steam to install prerequisites

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, c++, steam

I'm having issues with launching a game through Steam I've installed through flatpak. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Steam Flatpak Version 1.0.0.75.

I'm trying to run a game called SpaceEngineers, and i had it running on Wayland, but it seems when I switched to Xorg I get the following error when launching:

[image]

I haven't tried switching back to Wayland yet as Xorg has been working a LOT better for me on a few other games of mine. Just having issues with Space Engineers at the moment.

Things I've done to try and remedy this:
sudo apt purge g++
sudo apt install g++
sudo apt-get install build-essential

I've looked all over but can't really find much on this error or how to elevate steam to allow it to download this package. I'm also still pretty new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. Any guidance would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried in Wayland again as well and it seems I'm getting the exact same error.

Comment: From the space engineers discord:
opekope2 — Today at 5:34 PM
HERE'S THE WORKAROUND
1. Install and run protontricks
2. Navigate to SE > default prefix > regedit
3. Under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies, create Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14

Answer (score 0):

From space engineers discord:
opekope2 — Today at 5:34 PM
HERE'S THE WORKAROUND

1. Install and run protontricks
2. Navigate to SE > default prefix > regedit
3. Under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies, create  Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14

Comment: Welcome to U&L does fixing registry realy solve your ubuntu problem ?

Comment: Yes it did! I have however since switched to Pop!_OS and running Space Engineers on this OS (AMD Drivers) with GE-Proton7-55 compatibility runs just fine it seems.